# How do I keep deleting elements from a 2d list in python

Tags: python, algorithm

How do I continuously delete elements from a 2d list in python ?

I am trying to delete elements(1D list) in a 2D list  that satisfy a condition.

I tried this below but I keep getting a list index out of range error.

//Blocks is a 3D list where each row in the list represents a 2D list of a block. The 2D list contains coordinates on the board

```
for i in range(len(blocks)):
    for j in range(len(blocks[i])):
        print("The length of the block is",  range(len(blocks[i])))
        cell = blocks[i][j]
        if is_adjacent(cell, star1) or is_adjacent(cell, star2):
            print("delete:", blocks[i][j])
            del blocks[i][j]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You're modifying the list while you are iterating over it; that requires extra care, since the list (either inner or outer) gets shorter, while the original `len(blocks[i])` and `len(blocks)` stay the same (since these are evaluated only once, to calculate the range). You could try and iterate from end to start instead, since the changed list will be shortened from the end.

Comment: Not sure what is your overall goal here. Rather than deleting the cell, can you consider to set values to either True or False depending on the result of your `if` condition ? Does block[i][j] contain data that is serving some purpose ?

Comment: I am doing a forward checking algorithm for a constraint satisfaction problem. We need to delete cells that are invalid from the block.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to deal with this.

#### Quick and easy way:

Loop through the list from the end with

```
for j in range(len(blocks[i])-1, -1, -1)
```

#### Safer:

Use a new list. Append what you want to the new list. Then, replace the old list with the new list at the end

#### Safer but faster:

Same as previous approach, but only keep a new list of indices of the elements you want to keep.